# How to Use Program Values To Search In SQL SERVER

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am trying to use some values taken from the user in an SQL query and trying to search on basis of that input. I did a little research and found this on web.

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE 'userName%'");
```

I then tried changing it to

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='userName%'");
```

But that didn't work. Also I've tried using `'@userName'` but that doesn't work either. So Now I am here since clearly I am making some obvious mistake or none of the above methods are correct. Now if I hardcode the values

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='Anwer'");
```

it works fine. So I think I am making mistake on how to use the program's values.
I am using SQL Management Studio 2012 Programming Language Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user name is stored in a variable called `userName`, you would do this:

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='" + userName + "'");
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick I've been at it for hours now... Thankyou so much!

Comment: @Anwer I _highly_ suggest you read this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You should use a bind value instead of inlining the string.  That's prone to SQL injection attacks (hackers cleverly constructing an input value that lets them run arbitrary SQL).

Something like:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName=?");
ps.setString(1, "Anwer");
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: You could also remove the saving to a variable and make it a one liner. Just my $0.02

Comment: @ColeJohnson True, I did it that way because often people run the same prepared statement repeatedly and it is more efficient to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course PreparedStatements are a great option for many implementations. Depending on your use case,keep in mind additionally for Stored Procedures. Stored Procedures can have the PL/SQL compiled, prepared and optimized by the Database and have it called by your application. Example is shown below

```
String getUser= "{call getUser(?,?,?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getUser);
callableStatement.setString(1, "sampleUserName");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.executeUpdate(); //Excecute Stored Procedure

String firstName = callableStatement.getString(2);
String LastName = callableStatement.getString(3);
```